# how to take the input from user in Vagrant bash provisioning?

Tags: shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I want to take the userid and password as parameters for vagrant and then add them as environmental variable for deploying build. Earlier I was using a file to store credentials and using sync folder for passing them to the vagrant. Since its not safe to store password in file I was wondering is there a way we can prompt username and password during shell provisioning?